# Minecraft Server not restarting with Screen and Crontab upon reboot

Tags: linux, cron, sh, screen, minecraft

I have a Minecraft Server running on an server running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I have created a start script that uses Screen and works perfectly fine when run using the command line, but doesn't work when run in crontab.

start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "starting..." > ~/mcserver/started.txt
screen -dmS Server java -Xmx2G -Xmx7G -jar server.jar nogui
```

crontab

```
0 1 * * * reboot
@reboot 5 * * * * ~/mcserver/start.sh
```

The reboot happens at the scheduled time, but the server isn't started in the detached Screen 5 minutes later. The Screen is detached so I don't see the issue with my code.

Comment: You can't combine `@reboot` with a time specifier; if you want to sleep 5 minutes, then use something like `@reboot sleep 300 && screen -dmS Server java -Xmx2G -Xmx7G -jar /home/user/path/to/server.jar nogui`.
The syntax you attempted would try to run the command `5` with the arguments `*` (which expands to all the files in the current directory) four times, which of course is almost certainly a syntax error (which should have been reported in your logs) unless you have a command named `5` (and even then it probably doesn't do anything useful with these arguments and in this context).

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue and at first i specified the path of the jar file because apparently crotab is unable to find the server.jar file.

> start.sh

```
screen -dmS Server java -Xmx2G -Xmx7G -jar /home/user/path/to/server.jar nogui
```

Even after this change the script wasn't properly working (the screen session was constantly closing after the execution of the server.jar) and, for the same reason for the path of the jar file, crontab took the server.jar and it executed the server somewherelse, so it wasn't possible for it to find the eula.txt, causing to terminate the screen session. To fix this issue i had to, first of all, let crontab access the directory with the 'cd' command and then execute the jar file using the script.

> crontab -e

```
@reboot 5 * * * * cd /home/user/~/mcserver/ && /home/user/~/mcserver/start.sh
```

hope it helps.